# MS column chart showing arrows

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

Anybody can guide me why MS Column Chart is showing arrows. When I am displaying label values then start displaying it.

Please the below snap:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSChart uses SmartLabel Technology to display labels.

There are two ways you can get rid of your lines.

Disable the SmartLabel Technology

```
series.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = False;
```

But you may not like the end result as the labels might collide and your chart will become unreadable

Or you can selectively do this

```
s.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutStyle = LabelCalloutStyle.None;                                 
s.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineAnchorCapStyle = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
s.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But again it might confuse end user and the label might not be near the correct datapoint/bar

More Information here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.smartlabelstyle.aspx
http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/UsingSmartLabels.html

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This line is enough for removing arrow sign in chart.

```
series.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code its worked for me

***chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineAnchorCapStyle = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;***